# retrieve cookie value in cakephp

Tags: cookies, cakephp-2.0

I'm storing a multidimensional array in a cookie.

```
$this->Cookie->write('Cart',
                        $products, false, 3600
                    );
```

Below is the multidimensional array which I'm storing in the cookie

```
Array
(
    [Cart] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 
            [product_id] => 92
            [quantity] => 1
            [date_created] => 
            [date_modified] => 
            [product_name] => shoes
            [price] => 12
        )

)
```

but when i read the cookie, it gives me this output

```
[{\"Cart\":{\"user_id\":\"\",\"product_id\":\"7\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"date_created\":\"\",\"date_modified\":\"\",\"product_name\":\"iPhone\",\"price\":\"12\"}}]
```

below is the code which i'm using to read the cookie

```
$this->Cookie->read('Cart');
```

On my local server it works perfectly alright but gives me above mentioned output when I try it on Online server

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following to write

```
$this->Cookie->write('Cart', serialize($products), false, 3600);
```

And this to read

```
unserialize($this->Cookie->read('Cart'));
```

Your cookie is probably being saved as plain text.